# when to provide DbContextOptions in DbContext constructor vs OnConfiguring?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the difference between providing a `DbContext` constructor that accepts `DbContextOptions<MyFileContext>` versus including `OnConfiguring` method that wires-up database ?

Are the two are equivalent ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        // OPTION 1
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyFileContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<MyTable> MyTables { get; set; }

        // OPTION 2
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(AppSettingsProvider.MySqlServerConnection);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Comment: Quote from docs re option 2 `An application can simply instantiate such a context without passing anything to its constructor`

Answer (score 2):

> Are the two are equivalent ?

It's complicated. (But ideally no);

> The `DbContextOptions` can be supplied to the `DbContext` by overriding the `OnConfiguring` method ***or*** externally via a constructor argument.
>
> ***If both are used, `OnConfiguring` is applied last and can overwrite options supplied to the constructor argument.***

*emphasis mine*

### Reference [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)